# How to fix bundle version incompatibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course3-module3-movies
I use this repo , I  run `rake db:seed` Project want sqlite update and I add `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'` in `Gemfile` .
Project gives an error

```
(base) ➜  fullstack-course3-module3-movies git:(master) ✗ bundle
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
 In Gemfile:
   rails (= 4.2.4) was resolved to 4.2.4, which depends on
     bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

 Current Bundler version:
   bundler (2.0.1)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 4.2.4)', in any of the sources.
```

Answer (score 1):

You got Bundler `2.0.1` installed on your computer, but apparently your Gemfile requires `bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)`.

You can install the required bundler version like this:

`gem install bundler --version=1.x.y`